# Eventful api request_token method is not returning Request Token

Tags: php, api

I am trying to authenticate user using request_token method of eventful api (http://api.eventful.com/docs/auth). here is my code.

```
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth( array('use_ssl' => false, 'method' => 'POST')  );
$tmhOAuth->reconfigure(array('user_agent' => 'Eventful_PHP_API'));
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'http://eventful.com/oauth/request_token',
array(
'app_key' => 'app_key','oauth_callback' =>     'http://example.com/callback',
'oauth_consumer_key' => 'consumer_key',
'oauth_consumer_secret' => 'consumer_secret',
),true);
if($code == 200 ){
// success
}else{
// error
}
```

but I am getting an 404 error in $code. what can be wrong

Comment: Using `Postman` Chrome plug in I checked the link you're sending the request to, it returns `This page cannot be found. Here are some other events that we think you might like.`

Comment: Dan. you mean http://example.com/callback ? Offcourse it is fake. I used it just for example.

Comment: No, http://eventful.com/oauth/request_token

Comment: just call it in browser it will return the error. also look at http://api.eventful.com/docs/auth . thanks.

Comment: You can't load the page in your browser, you have to send a POST request to that URL.  I'm saying that it's returning a 404 error because that's what is happening on that page.

Comment: so you are saying that their api is not working? http://api.eventful.com/docs/auth

Comment: I'm saying that there's a 404 being returned from the URL that you're working with - see more below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include additional parameters in your `POST` request.

As noted in the [Eventful API Docs](http://api.eventful.com/docs/auth):

> - All oAuth requests must be signed with HMAC-SHA1 signatures. //Looks like you're not doing this
> - All oAuth requests must contain timestamp and nonce parameters. //You're not doing this either
> - If you get a 404 when requesting data you are probably either making a GET request when a POST Is required, not sending the correct parameters, or are not computing the signature with the correct parameters. If you have problems please enter in all relevant parameters into this form and see what signature it computes. Compare it with what signature you are actually sending. Rember to enter in your app_key and any other parameters you send into the parameters line and set the HTTP method to the correct value. For the initial request token live the token and token_secret blank.

The example they provide includes several query string parameters that you are not including, like `oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_nonce`, `oauth_signature`, `oauth_signature_method`, `oauth_timestamp`, and  `oauth_version`.

Their example:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&oauth_consumer_key=bafe29a8e561b3d15803&oauth_nonce=1cdb7f498ba9811513f2&oauth_signature=8EfteAvDBuE8MTVBABg2WhXnzY0%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1336765460&oauth_version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: tmhOAuth take cares of hmac-sha1, nonce and timestamp. you can try it. it is small script.

Answer (score 0):

ok. After 1 day of research I found the answer. here is the modified code.

```
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
'application_key'    => 'my_app_key',
'consumer_key' => 'my_consumer_key',
'consumer_secret'  => 'my_consumer_secret'
));
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'http://eventful.com/oauth/request_token',
array(
'oauth_callback'  => "http://example.com/callback"
));

if($code == 200 ){
// success
}else{
// error
}
```

Special thanks to 'tekin' (https://github.com/tekin) of his ruby eventful api for providing the guidance ( https://github.com/tekin/eventful_api )